# Problem with multivariables in string formatting

Tags: python-3.x

I have several files in a folder named `t_000.png`, `t_001.png`, `t_002.png` and so on. 
I have made a for-loop to import them using string formatting. But when I use the for-loop I got the error

`No such file or directory: '/file/t_0.png'`

This is the code that I have used I think I should use multiple %s but I do not understand how.

```py
for i in range(file.shape[0]):
        im    = Image.open(dir + 't_%s.png' % str(i))
        file[i] = im
```

Comment: What happens if you run: `import os` then `os.listdir()`? Also, please provide the code leading into this. What is the value in `dir`?

Comment: Are you trying to access the contents of the file or you are concerned with their names? Please clarify

Comment: dir is the path to the directory where the files are dir = /share/Desktop/file/

Comment: If you want 3 decimal places left-padded with `'0'`s, tell the formatter (and let the formatter do the number to digits conversion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pad the string with leading zeroes. With the type of formatting you're currently using, this should work:

```
im = Image.open(dir + 't_%03d.png' % i)
```

where the format string `%03s` means "this should have length 3 characters and empty space should be padded by leading zeroes".

You can also use python's other (more recent) string formatting syntax, which is somewhat more succinct:

```
im = Image.open(f"{dir}t_{i:03d}")
```

Comment: The first approach does not work, should be `'t_%03d.png' % i`, as `d` is for `int` objects, not `str`.

Comment: @norok2 you're absolutely right, I did that in my python console when I was testing it but forgot to do it here. Answer has been fixed accordingly, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not padding the number with zeros, thus you get `t_0.png` instead of `t_000.png`.

The recommended way of doing this in Python 3 is via the `str.format` function:

```py
for i in range(file.shape[0]):
        im    = Image.open(dir + 't_{:03d}.png'.format(i))
        file[i] = im
```

You can see more examples in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples).

[Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) are also an option if you are using Python 3.6 or a more recent version, see Green Cloak Guy's answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import os


for i in range(file.shape[0]):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(dir, f't_{i:03d}.png'))
    file[i] = im
```

(change: `f't_{i:03d}.png'` to `'t_{:03d}.png'.format(i)` or `'t_%03d.png' % i` for versions of Python prior to 3.6).

The trick was to specify a certain number of leading zeros, take a look at the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec) for more info.

Also, you should replace 'dir + file' with the more robust `os.path.join(dir, file)`, which would work regardless of `dir` ending with a directory separator (i.e. '/' for your platform) or not.

Note also that both `dir` and `file` are reserved names in Python and you may want to rename your variables.
Also check that if `file` is a NumPy array, `file[i] = im` may not be working.